# Web Speech API in Chrome in iOS throws "service-not-allowed" error

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, webspeech-api

i am currently implementing speech input on a website and using the web speech API for it.

voice recognition works as expected in Chrome on desktop and android. Firefox does not have support for the API so it is not being used there.

the problem is with chrome on iOS where the service throws a "service-not-allowed" error.

this error seems to be distinctly different from the "not-allowed" error that is being thrown when the browser does not have permission to use the microphone.

in my case chrome has all permissions it would need (microphone permission, pop-ups are not blocked).

at first i thought the problem was, that for some reason chrome on iOS does not show me the permission pop-up, specifically for microphone usage, directly on the web page, but now i am not so sure anymore.

does anyone have experience with this problem or have a solution for this?

here is the working code for android/desktop, the function gets triggered by a button click:

```
function startDictation() {
    try {
        var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
        var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    if (recognition) {
        recognition.continuous = false;
        recognition.interimResults = true;

        recognition.lang = $('html').attr('lang');
        recognition.start();

        recognition.onresult = function(e) {
            $('#searchInput').val(e.results[0][0].transcript);
            console.log(e.results[0][0].transcript);
        };

        recognition.onerror = (e) => {
            console.error('Speech recognition error detected: ' + e.error);
            recognition.stop();
        };

        recognition.onend = () => {
            console.log('Speech recognition service disconnected');
        }

    }
}
```

a few helpful links

- [web speech api error values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent/error)
- [web speech api demo from google](https://www.google.com/intl/de/chrome/demos/speech.html), that also doesn't work on iOS for me

i have tried various end devices at this point, two different iPads and an iPhone and the same error gets thrown everywhere.

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#dom-speechrecognitionerrorcode-service-not-allowed), there's a number of reasons why the error would show up. Can you test your code in Safari iOS, just to see if it would fail there as well? If it doesn't, then it's something Chrome related. If it does, then it might be something iOS related.

Comment: @FiddlingAway the code works fine in Safari iOS, it's the particular combination of Chrome + iOS that fails, so it does seem to be an iOS issue to me